# Using python win32com can't make two separate tables in MS Word 2007

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I am trying to create multiple tables in a new Microsoft Word document using Python.  I can create the first table okay. But I think I have the COM Range object configured wrong.  It is not pointing to the end.  The first table is put before "Hello I am a text!", the second table is put inside the first table's first cell.  I thought that returning a Range from wordapp will return the full range, then collapse it using wdCollapseStart Enum which I think is 1.  (I can't find the constants in Python win32com.).  So adding a table to the end of the Range will add it to the end of the document but that is not happening.

Any ideas?

Thanks Tim

```
import win32com.client

wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application") 
wordapp.Visible = 1 
worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Add()
worddoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 
worddoc.PageSetup.BookFoldPrinting = 1 
worddoc.Content.Font.Size = 11
worddoc.Content.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add (100)
worddoc.Content.Text = "Hello, I am a text!"

location = worddoc.Range()
location.Collapse(1)
location.Paragraphs.Add()
location.Collapse(1)
table = location.Tables.Add (location, 3, 4)
table.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = 1
table.AutoFormat(16)
table.Cell(1,1).Range.InsertAfter("Teacher")

location1 = worddoc.Range()
location1.Paragraphs.Add()
location1.Collapse(1)
table = location1.Tables.Add (location1, 3, 4)
table.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = 1
table.AutoFormat(16)
table.Cell(1,1).Range.InsertAfter("Teacher1")
worddoc.Content.MoveEnd
worddoc.Close() # Close the Word Document (a save-Dialog pops up)
wordapp.Quit() # Close the Word Application
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the Range object that represents a part of the document.  In my original code the Range object contains the first cell and starts at the first cell, where it will insert.  Instead I want to insert at the end of the range.  So I got the following code replacement to work.  I moved the Collapse after the Add() call and gave it an argument of 0. Now there is only one Collapse call per Range object.

```
location = worddoc.Range()
location.Paragraphs.Add()
location.Collapse(0)
```

Now the code works, I can read from a database and populate new tables from each entry.

Tim