# pywin32 excel to word overwrite issue

Tags: python, excel, com, ms-word, pywin32

Below is my code and i am using both pywin32 and xlrd. The problem here is that my xls has multiple sheets and sheets are accessed one by on and written to a word document and when the code writes to word documents it overwrites the content of the previous sheet. WHat i am seeking is that i need to append my data one by one. If any one could provide solution i would be grateful because i need it for problem i am working on:

```
from win32com import client
import xlrd
book1 = xlrd.open_workbook("E:/excel2word/454184_Appendix E 300713 Worcester NH.xls",formatting_info=True)
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open("E:/excel2word/Doc1.docx")
book = excel.Workbooks.Open("E:/excel2word/454184_Appendix E 300713 Worcester NH.xls")
count = book.Sheets.Count
print count
mapping ={'1':'A','2':'B','3':'C','4':'D','5':'E','6':'F','7':'G','8':'H','9':'I','10':'J','11':'K'}
for i in xrange(1,count+1):
    sh = book1.sheet_by_index(i-1)
    sheet = book.Worksheets(i)
    print sheet
    sheet.Range("A4:"+str(mapping[str(sh.ncols)])+""+str(sh.nrows)).Copy()
    print "A4:"+str(mapping[str(sh.ncols)])+""+str(sh.nrows)
    doc.Content.PasteExcelTable(False,False,False)
```

Comment: Why are you reading from the excel file with BOTH xlrd and COM?  And when you do this your `PasteExcelTable` overwrites the previous `PasteExcelTable`?

Comment: Yes it overwrites the previous table. Do you have a solution sir?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue here.
And I finally have a solution after a lot of search.....
You need to use the Range.Collapse and Range.MoveEnd

```
range1 = doc.Range()
range1.Collapse(0)
range1.MoveEnd()
range1.PasteExcelTable(False,False,False)
```

Comment: I used some information from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882240/using-python-win32com-cant-make-two-separate-tables-in-ms-word-2007